# Add Requested Debug Information to FAQ

Tags: feature-request

Reference this question:
[Where do I get "Bug Information" to add to a question?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question)

We do often ask people to indicate the debugging steps they have taken. This is a reasonable request, as it cuts to the quick of any issue, and ensures that WPSE members don't have to walk anyone through *ad nauseum* steps to identify the root issue.

However, I can't find those steps listed anywhere to be referenced by new users. I can see how the experience would be frustrating for new users: ask a question, receive a terse comment asking about debugging, and then having the question closed. While many such questions are "drive-by" anyway, I think we run the risk of frustrating sincere users who simply do not know of the debugging expectation.

Shouldn't this expectation be listed in our FAQ, along with a list of typical debugging steps?

### Edit

Requested debug information:

1. Identify active Theme
2. Identify active Plugins
3. Identify WordPress version
4. Ensure `WP_DEBUG` is set to `true`, and report any PHP fatal errors or notices/warnings, as appropriate
5. Include code from any line numbers referenced in PHP debug output

(Please add to the list as necessary.)